# Altium pad features and difference between Hole Size and "X-size and Y-size under Size and Shape"

Tags: pcb-design, altium, through-hole

Could someone please explain what the green bit in the center is and what the silver ring on the outside represents? I'm trying to create a hole of a certain size and just want to know the difference between 'Hole Size' and "X-size and Y-size under Size and Shape".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green portion represents the hole and grey portion represents the pad surrounding the hole for electrical/mechanical connectivity.

So in pad properties,

1. Hole Size: Specify the hole size. (It is advisable to increase the hole size by some percent to ensure smooth entry/exit from the hole)
2. X-axis: Size of the pad in x-dimension(left-right)
3. Y-axis: Size of the pad in y-dimension(top-bottom)

The value of X-axis and Y-axis will be same if your pad is circular, and different otherwise

Comment: The holes that I'm trying to make are for a battery holder and are only there for support. There will be no electrical connection to these holes. So should I keep the X and Y axis bigger than the Hole Size? Is there a way to make sure that these cannot be electrically connected? Would tenting them make sense for this purpose?

Comment: Yes make them slightly (0.2 to 0.3 mm) bigger.
Do not tent them. Just ensure that there are no wires or polygon pours around these pads and you'll be good. Tenting isn't a good idea if you want to put solder on those pads